# Matrix Least Squares on the Rows Instead of Columns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-optimization, least-squares, linear-regression

I want to solve the equation $AB=C, A\epsilon \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}, B\epsilon \mathbb{Z}^{3\times 10}, C\epsilon \mathbb{R}^{3\times 10}$ for $A$. The solution should minimize the norm (best is euclidean) of the columns of $AB-C$.

My first attempt was to transpost the whole equation ($B^TA^T=C^T$) and apply an ordinary linear regression, but this would minimize the norm of the rows of $AB-C$ instead of the columns.

How could one minimize the columns of  $AB-C$ instead? Or (what would be the same) minimize the rows of $B^TA^T-C^T$ as a solution of $B^TA^T=C^T$.

Background: $A$ is the basis of a lattice. $B$ is an integer matrix that selects lattice points. The columns of $C$ are noisy lattice points. So I am searching for a lattice, that describes the noisy lattice points best (best in the sense, that the norms between predicted and real lattice points are minimal).

Comment: What is the "norm of the columns"? What variables are you solving for?

Comment: @DanPiponi I want to solve for $A$. $AB-C$ is a 3x10 defect matrix. The mean norm of the columns of this defect matrix should be minimized.

Comment: What about something like $ \arg \min_{A} \left\| \boldsymbol{1}^{T} \left( A B - C \right) \right\|_{2}^{2} $? It's Convex and easily solvable.

Comment: @Royi: okay, it might be worth a try. How do I solve it? At the moment I use the C++ library Eigen. It can do some decompositions (QR, SVD) and also offers a Levenberg Marquardt implementation. Maybe you can suggest an other free C++ library to solve it.

Comment: @Royi: Damn, this is not a good idea... summing up the columns of the defect matrix leads to extinction of positive with negative values . Something that we do not want.

Comment: @yar, I agree. I think I found a better way. Look below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define $ D = A B - C $.
Then in order to minimize the Least Squares per each column of $ D $ one could do the following:

$$ \arg \min_{A} \sum_{i} \left\| \left( A B - C \right) \boldsymbol{e}_{i} \right\|_{2}^{2} $$

Where $ \boldsymbol{e}_{i} $ is the $ i $ -th columns of the identity matrix $ I \in \mathbb{R}^{10 \times 10} $.

The above indeed extracts each column of the matrix $ D $ and calculates its $ {L}_{2} $ Norm.
The optimization problem tries to minimize that.

Yet, what's happening here is basically using the [Frobenious Norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm).
Thence the problem can be written as:

$$ \arg \min_{A} \left\| A B - C \right\|_{F}^{2} $$

Now, by defining $ f \left( A \right) = \left\| A B - C \right\|_{F}^{2} $ one could see that:

$$ \frac{d}{d A} f \left( A \right) = 2 \left( A B - C \right) {B}^{T} $$

Taking the derivative to zero yields:

$$ \hat{A} = C {B}^{T} \left( B {B}^{T} \right)^{-1} $$

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks! (and of course also thanks to @LeGrandDODOM !).

Comment: You're welcome. Enjoy!

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM , @ Royi After thinking about the solution once again, I recognized, that the solution is right, but it minimizes the "wrong" cost function. Unfortunately I did not write the cost function I want to minimize, so "wrong" is probably not the right word. It minimizes the sum of the squared norms of the columns, but I wanted to minimize the sum of the norms of the columns.The point is, that minimizing the sum of the squared euclidean norms of the columns is the same as minimizing the sum of the squared euclidean norms of the rows, so $CB^{-1}$(pseudo inverse) would do the same job =(

Comment: The found solution is actually the definition of the pseudoinverse for a full-rank-matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Letting $\|\cdot\|$ denote the Frobenius norm on the space of $3\times 10$ matrices, you 're likely interested in the optimisation problem $$\min_{A\in \mathbb R^{3\times 3}} \|AB-C\|^2 $$

Since the Frobenius norm comes from the inner product $(X,Y) \mapsto trace(X^TY)$, the problem is tractable.

It's easy to prove $\mathbb R^{3\times 3} \to \mathbb R^{3\times 10} , A\mapsto \|AB-C\|$ is convex (essentially because of the triangle inequality). Since $[0,\infty) \to \mathbb R, x\mapsto x^2$ is convex and increasing, $\mathbb R^{3\times 3} \to \mathbb R, A \mapsto \|AB-C\|^2$ is convex.

To solve the problem, you need only find some $A$ where the Fréchet derivative of $A \mapsto \|AB-C\|^2$ is $0$. Let us compute this derivative for arbitrary $A$: since $$\|(A+H)B-C\|^2 =\|AB-C\|^2 + trace(((AB-C)B^T)^TH) + \|HB\|^2 $$
the Fréchet derivative at $A$ is $H\mapsto trace(((AB-C)B^T)^TH)$

This is $0$ when $(AB-C)B^T=0$. If $rank(B)=3$, this is the same as $A=CB^T(BB^T)^{-1}$.

$CB^T(BB^T)^{-1}$ is a solution to the problem, provided $rank(B)=3$.

Comment: I think it should be $ \hat{A} = C {B}^{T} \left( B {B}^{T} \right)^{-1} $. See my answer (I think you were writing your answer at the same time I finished mine hence you didn't see it).

Comment: @Royi, yes, thanks for catching that.